# Does Scalatest provider a matcher for NaN?

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

Does Scalatest provide a matcher for `NaN` and infinities?

I would like to make these assertions a bit more descriptive if there's a way:

```scala
Double.NaN.isNaN shouldBe true
Double.NegativeInfinity.isInfinite shouldBe true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most flexible way to handle this is probably using ScalaTest's [support for symbols to handle boolean matches on properties.](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingBooleanPropertiesWithBe) So, the following tests all work and give a pretty useful error message on failure:

```
class DoubleSpec extends FreeSpec with Matchers {

  "NaN should be NaN" in {
    Double.box(Double.NaN) shouldBe 'NaN
  }

  "1 should not be NaN" in {
    Double.box(1d) should not be 'NaN
  }

  "Infinity should be infinite" in {
    Double.box(Double.PositiveInfinity) shouldBe 'Infinite
  }

  "1 should not be infinite" in {
    Double.box(1d) should not be 'Infinite
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, symbol support only exists for reference types - there's an implicit parameter `T <:< AnyRef` required. I welcome suggestions for handling this without needing to call `Double.box` every single time.

You can also write your own matchers for this:

```
  val NaN : BeMatcher[Double] = (left: Double) => MatchResult(
    left.isNaN,
    s"$left is not NaN",
    s"$left is NaN"
  )

  "NaN should be NaN" in {
    Double.NaN shouldBe NaN
  }

  "1 should not be NaN" in {
    1d should not be NaN
  }
```

Avoids the boxing problem and is more type-safe, but does require a few extra lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, NaN is not equal to anything (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=NaN#Comparison_with_NaN).

For this reason I don't think any scalatest matcher would and should exist for NaN and you would better use .isNaN as you already done.

As for infinite values, you may equally use :

```
val value = -1.0/0.0
value.isNegInfinity shouldBe true
value.isInfinite shouldBe true
value should equal (Double.NegativeInfinity)
```